# How can i do a numerical integration of the following expression?

Tags: python, scipy, pytorch, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I am currently trying to evaluate the following expression in Python

[image]

The expression comes from a t-distribution and v is a scalar indicating degrees of freedom, mu and sigma is a vector and a matrix respectively, defining the mean and the standard deviation. How would I go on getting a numerical integration of the expression? I have tried the following using PyTorch and Scipy quad function:

```
def integrand(x, mu, std,v,p):
    return torch.sum((1+(x-mu)**2*std**(-2)/v)**((-v+p)/2)*torch.log(1+x**2/v))

integrate.quad(integrand, -np.inf,np.inf, args=(mu,std,v,p))[0]
```

However, the results are quite disappointing. The thing that bugs me are the vectors, I don't think I know how to handle such a situation, also the limits are not specified. Help would very much be appreciated, thanks a lot! Let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: Could you clarify what type of solution you are looking for? Is it a numerical approximation of the integral for z from -infinity to +infinity or are you looking for a closed form for the indefinite integral? If it's the latter case such an expression may not exist.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the image! :) I am looking for a numerical approximation for the integral of z. The limits have not been given, but i would assume they are -infinity to +infinity.

Comment: It's not clear what `z` vs `bold(z)` is. Also, please provide a _complete_ example  (including all `import`s and variable definitions) that everyone can just copy and paste to see the error. Keep it as simple as possible though.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Nico! They don't specify what z and bold(z) is in the paper, I think it may be an error? The paper is here: 
https://www.elen.ucl.ac.be/Proceedings/esann/esannpdf/es2019-42.pdf 
My code is very long, basically a variational autoencoder, the above integration method I tried is completely wrong, just maybe someone could explain how i would evaluate such integral :)

Comment: You say the results are disappointing then talk about vectors.  It is not clear what you mean.  Does it crash, not return, give numbers that don't make sense?  Also, you seem to be using a canned routine integrate.quad(), which I assume is Gaussian quadrature but are you sure you've analyzed the integrand for singularities and other irregularities that might cause issues?  I am familiar with writing my own Quad functions but not the canned interface.  There could be some subtleties.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but this question does not seem solved.

Bold z (**z**) is usually used for vector notation, and it checks out in this case, since the left part in the integral is the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) of the [multivariate t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution).

What seems to be problematic in your case is the way that you compute vector multiplication.

First and foremost, if `x` is a list/array, `(x-mu)**2` will not even compute, so I assume that x is a Numpy array. Thus, using a `numpy` array with the power operator computes the element-wise powers:

```
> np.array([1,2,3])**2
array([1, 4, 9])
```

However, the multivariate density kernel you are trying to evaluate is a scalar function (as in it outputs a scalar). This implies that your vector notation is in columns by default and **z**<sup>T</sup>**z** is a scalar. Therefore, you would have to sum the vector squared: `sum((x-mu)**2)`.

What bugs me presently is that, if you use the multivariate t-distribution, then you have a multivariate integral, and I don't quite know how `scipy.integrate` handles this, unless you [integrate on a path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). You could consider alternatives such as `scipy.nquad`, etc.